# Extjs Sandbox charts inside tabpanel and card layout

Tags: extjs, charts, sandbox, extjs4.1

I have an extjs 3.4 application using extjs 4.1 sandbox charts.  The only problem I have is that in IE8 they don't render completely once activated from a tabpanel layout or when called from a card layout.

Nothing too special about the code:

```
var barBreakdownChart = Ext4.create('Ext4.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.get('barBreakdownDiv').dom,
    width: 550,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: geosPeerChartStore,
    legend: true,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        title: 'Days of Supply',
        fields: ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        labelTitle: {
          font: '14px "Lucida Grande"'
        },
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        // label: {
        //     rotate: {
        //         degrees: 315
        //     }
        // },
        fields: ['name']
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        fill: true,
        //title: 'Current Year',
        axis: 'left',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('line1') + ' $');
            }
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5']
        ,title: ['2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012']
    }]
});
```

then here is where the charts are being called inside a tabpanel:

```
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;',
            height: 400,
            deferredRender: false,
            defaults: {
                hideMode: 'offsets'
            },
            activeTab: 0,
            items: [{
                title: 'Line Chart',
                items: lineBreakdownContainer
            }, {
                xtype:'panel',
                html: '<div id="barBreakdownDiv"> </div>'
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with styles.
Try using another css, (i.e. ext-ie-debug.css) instead resource/css/ext-all.css